# Scoping and imports in Xtext

Tags: java, xtext

I've got the following Xtext grammar:

```
Model:
    'model' name = ID imports += Import* items += Item* rules += Rule*;

Import:
    'import' importURI = STRING;

Rule:
    'rule' name = ID '(' items += [Item]* ')';

Item:
    'item' name = ID;
```

When opening the editor, all `Item` references in `Rule`s are hilighted correctly if they are in the same file, and I can jump to the declaration using F3. However, that doesn't work if I try to import them from other files. For example:

File `first.mydsl`

```
model first
import "second.mydsl"
rule myRule (second)
```

File `second.mydsl`

```
model second
item second
```

Assuming these two files are in the same folder, it still won't find the 'second' reference from the imported file. It also doesn't work if I include the file extension for the imported file, or the full path.
How do I get Xtext to recognize the imported file?

(crossposted to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/805182/#msg_805182)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you configure your workflow as follows

```
        // scoping and exporting API
        fragment = scoping.ImportURIScopingFragment {}
        fragment = exporting.SimpleNamesFragment {}

        // scoping and exporting API
        // fragment = scoping.ImportNamespacesScopingFragment {}
        // fragment = exporting.QualifiedNamesFragment {}
        // fragment = builder.BuilderIntegrationFragment {}
        ....
        // fragment = types.TypesGeneratorFragment {}
```

Comment: I changed my config as you suggested. Now it's throwing `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot override final binding 'final org.eclipse.xtext.naming.IQualifiedNameProvider -> org.eclipse.xtext.naming.SimpleNameProvider (contributed by org.eclipse.xtext.generator.exporting.SimpleNamesFragment)'` whenever I generate the artifacts.

Comment: have you added something else to your workflow? can you post the complete stacktrace?